# What does this XSLT fragment do?

Tags: xml, xslt

Can anyone tell me, what the XSLT is doing here? It's a part of a longer XSLT-document.

```
<xsl:template match="node[child::attribute[@NAME='entity']]">
<xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="child::attribute[@NAME='entity']/@VALUE='accessval'">
        <xsl:element name="access">
            <xsl:apply-templates />
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:when test="child::attribute[@NAME='entity']/@VALUE='aclval'">
        <xsl:element name="acl">
            <xsl:apply-templates />
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:when>
    </xsl:choose>
</template>
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will match any `node` element that has an `attribute` element child with `NAME="entity"`, and based on the `VALUE` attribute of that `attribute` element it will rename the `node` to either `access` or `acl` and then continue processing its children, i.e. given:

```
<node>
  <attribute NAME="entity" VALUE="accessval"/>
  <!-- other elements here -->
</node>
```

it would produce

```
<access>
  <!-- result of applying templates to "attribute" and "other elements here" -->
</access>
```

and if the `VALUE` were "aclval" it would produce an element named `acl` rather than `access`.

If there were more than one `<attribute NAME="entity" VALUE="something" />` inside the `node` then the *first* matching `xsl:when` inside the `xsl:choose` would win, i.e. given

```
<node>
  <attribute NAME="entity" VALUE="aclval"/>
  <attribute NAME="entity" VALUE="accessval"/>
  <!-- other elements here -->
</node>
```

the resulting element would be `access`, not `acl` because it checks for "accessval" before "aclval".